# How to split data from string?

Tags: c#, string, split

How can i split data from string?

I have my string like this,

```
Url=http://www.yahoo.com UrlImage=http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/yahoo_logo_in_061509.png UrlTitle=Yahoo! India UrlDescription=Welcome to Yahoo!, the world's most visited home page. Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know with the latest news and information.
```

I want this information to be split like

```
http://www.yahoo.com

http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/yahoo_logo_in_061509.png

Yahoo! India

Welcome to Yahoo!, the world's most visited home page. Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know with the latest news and information.
```

How can i split above string into these four parts and saving into temp variable for each part?

string url= http://www.yahoo.com

string urlImage= http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/yahoo_logo_in_061509.png

string urlTitle= Yahoo! India

string urlDescription= Welcome to Yahoo!, the world's most visited home page. Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know with the latest news and information.

How can i do that?

Comment: You'll probably have to write a parser for it yourself. How have you defined your string format? "Key:Value" where the value terminates after the next block you can parse as a key? How do you encode values that contain colons?

Comment: Is there always 4 parts? You can use String.IndexOf(' ') or LINQ SkipWhile/TakeWhile/Take/Skip...

Comment: can you please provide/reference an example for it?

Comment: Your input string has a big problem. You're using ':' as the key/value delimeter, but one or more of the data points also contain a ':' character. This will make it much harder to parse this. You could try escaping the problem characters in the data, or changing the key/value delimiter to another character.

Comment: @MattDavey: I have changes it to = from :. Hope this will be ok. Now how can i split this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that format of your input string will not change (ie the order of the keys), you could try something like this:

```
var input = "Url:http://www.yahoo.com UrlImage:http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/yahoo_logo_in_061509.png UrlTitle:Yahoo! India UrlDescription:Welcome to Yahoo!, the world's most visited home page. Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know with the latest news and information."

// Convert the input string into a format which is easier to split...
input = input.Replace("Url=", "")
             .Replace("UrlImage=", "|")
             .Replace("UrlTitle=", "|")
             .Replace("UrlDescription=", "|");

var splits = input.Split("|");

string url         = splits[0]; // = http://www.yahoo.com
string image       = splits[1]; // = http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/yahoo_logo_in_061509.png
string title       = splits[2]; // = Yahoo! India
string description = splits[3]; // = Welcome to Yahoo!, the world's...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var input = "Url:http://www.yahoo.com UrlImage:http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/yahoo_logo_in_061509.png UrlTitle:Yahoo! India UrlDescription:Welcome to Yahoo!, the world's most visited home page. Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know with the latest news and information.";

var result = input.Split(new []{"Url:","UrlImage:","UrlTitle:","UrlDescription:"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```